# Spinner wont show dropdown in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, spinner, android-spinner

I have created a Fragment called **PaletteFragment** that includes a spinner. However, when I click on the spinner, the dropdown items do not appear. It is allowing me to click on the spinner, but doesn't do anything. The spinner **did work** when the assignment didn't require me to use fragments (as shown below) but now that we are required to use fragments, the spinner does not work even though I'm getting no errors in the logcat.

[image]

This is what I am trying to get again from the fragment
[image]

This is what I am getting after moving my PaletteActivity to my fragment

Here is my **PaletteFragment**

```
package edu.temple.coloractivity;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import java.util.Locale;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link PaletteFragment #newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class PaletteFragment extends Fragment {

    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    public static PaletteFragment newIntance(){
        return new PaletteFragment();
    }
    public PaletteFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment PaletteFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static PaletteFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        PaletteFragment fragment = new PaletteFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_palette, container, false);
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                getActivity(), R.array.myColors, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> stringNames = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.myStrings, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        stringNames.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> stringName = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),R.array.myStrings, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        stringName.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_palette,container,false);
        spinner = v.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if(position == 0){
                }
                else if(position == 1){
                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), CanvasActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("position",1);
                    startActivity(i);
                }else if(position == 2){
                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), CanvasActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("position",2);
                    startActivity(i);
                }else if(position == 3){
                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), CanvasActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("position",3);
                    startActivity(i);
                }else if(position == 4){
                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), CanvasActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("position",4);
                    startActivity(i);
                }else if(position == 5){
                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), CanvasActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("position",5);
                    startActivity(i);
                }else if(position == 6){
                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), CanvasActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("position",6);
                    startActivity(i);
                }else if(position == 7){
                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), CanvasActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("position",7);
                    startActivity(i);
                }else if(position == 8){
                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), CanvasActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("position",8);
                    startActivity(i);
                }else if(position == 9){
                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), CanvasActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("position",9);
                    startActivity(i);
                }else if(position == 10){
                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), CanvasActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("position",10);
                    startActivity(i);
                }

            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

}
```

Here is my **PaletteActivity**

```
package edu.temple.coloractivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;

import java.util.Locale;


public class PaletteActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        PaletteFragment PaletteFragment = new PaletteFragment();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.firstLayout,PaletteFragment,PaletteFragment.getTag())
                .commit();
    }
}
```

This is the relevant code hopefully it is enough to spot what I am doing wrong, if not I'll post the whole code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You doing everything ok, except your are not binding adapter with spinner.
Use this to set Adapter for spinner.

```
stringName.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_palette,container,false);
            spinner = v.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
            spinner.setAdapter(stringName )
```